# Perform an action in Excel for each column for each set of rows with the same row label

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies for the confusing question title, I wasn't sure how to describe the problem.

Background and objectives:
I have a large dataset in Excel, near 1 Million rows.
I have a key field (not primary cause there's duplicates).
The key field will become the primary key field in a new table.
For every row with the same key field in the original dataset, I need to:
 Find the max of one of the columns
 See if a text string exists in one of the columns
Then I'd like to put the key field, the corresponding max, and the corresponding result of the text search into a new dataset in one row, 3 columns.

A VBA or PivotTable solution is acceptable.  Given the size of the dataset, code efficiency/memory management is critical.

Thanks in advance, any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: what roadblocks do you encounter when solving this problem?

Comment: Where to start.  At the moment I'm attempting to use a pivot table.

Comment: At the moment, one column.  It's possible that a max value is duplicated, but a duplicated max won't disrupt what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Max values are now covered using pivot tables.  No idea how to handle text fields for my condition using a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pivotTable, "Key" field dragged to the row labels and in the "Values" section, put in the columns that you want to determine the MAX. Go to Value Field Settings -> Summarize Value field by, set it to "MAX"

Comment: Excellent.  This solution worked for max values, how do I take care of text fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this since I was able to solve the problem with everyone's help.

In case someone hits this in the future, I didn't discover how to run formulas against text fields with pivot tables, but I calculated a numerical value in another column in the original dataset and was able to use that.

Thanks!